# Type mismatch error in excel 2013 but works in excel 2010 when using ADODB.Recordset

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

When I am running the following VBA code in excel 2010 it works but shows up an error message when running it on excel 2013. It shows up Compile Error : Type Mismatch and highlights rsLCC.RecordCount

```
Public Sub LoadRegionCombo()

Dim sLCC_SQL As String
Dim rsLCC As New ADODB.Recordset
Set rsLCC = New ADODB.Recordset

On Error GoTo Err_LoadRegionCombo

Call SetDataPath
Call OpenConnection

sQrySub1 = "CONTRACTORS"

QCArr2(0) = "COMBOS"
QCArr2(1) = "ComboSQL"
QCArr2(2) = ""  ' sFilter1
QCArr2(3) = ""  ' sFilter2
QCArr2(4) = "ASC"
QCArr2(5) = sQrySub1
QCArr2(6) = ""   'sQrySub2

sLCC_SQL = QryCall2(QCArr2())
rsLCC.Open sLCC_SQL, ExelCon, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly

ipCount = rsLCC.RecordCount
```

Comment: See if this is the same as what you are facing? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983246 Is MSOFFICE 2013 64 bit?

Comment: Thanks a tonne!! this is exactly what i am facing.

Comment: Glad to be of help :D

Answer (score 3):

Wrap

```
.RecordCount
```

with

```
CLng(.RecordCount)
```

Comment: Maybe change `.RecordCount` to `rsLCC.RecordCount` to make it more understandable?

Comment: it would be better to also give a little explanation of what is going on in your answer